# Find the length of the arc of the curve $x= y^5/5 + 1/(12y^3)$ over $[2,4]$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find the length of the arc of the curve 
$$x= \frac{y^5}{5} + \frac{1}{12y^3}$$ over the interval $[2,4]$. 
I know I need to find $$\int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{ 1+\Big(\frac{dx}{dy}\Big)^2} dy$$ because that's the 'formula' to find arc length. I want to make sure I am starting the problem off correctly by checking if I did the derivative correctly: $$\frac{dx}{dy}=y^4 - \frac{1}{4y^4}.$$ If that is correct then I have to square $dy/dx$ and when I did this I got 
$$\Big(\frac{dx}{dy}\Big)^2 = y^8 - \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{16y^8}.$$ Then I plugged this into the formula above and got 
$$\int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{y^8+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{16y^2}} \, dy$$ which is a perfect square. So now I have $$\int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{\Big(y^4+\frac{1}{4y^4}\Big)^2} dy$$ and this leaves me with $$\int_{2}^{4} \Big(y^4+\frac{1}{4y^4}\Big) \,dy.$$ When I integrate this i got y^5/5-1/12y^3 invaluated at 4 and 2. once plugging in the 4 and then the 2 i got the answer 992/5 - 1/1500 + 1/96. is this correct?

Comment: I think you may want the square of dx/dy instead of dy/dx in your second equation.

Comment: $\int{ax^{b}dx} = \frac{ax^{b+1}}{b+1}$ for **any** $b \neq -1$. Just apply this formula to what you have finding what are $a$ and $b$ for each term.

Comment: Wouldn't $ \int \frac{1}{4y^4}dy$ be $-\frac{1}{12y^3}$ instead of $-\frac{1}{3y^3}$?

Comment: @HDE226868 yes you are right. i dropped the 1/4 on accident.

Answer (score 1):

Just a word of the wise: I don't know what went through your head, but remember that your final equation should be equal to the **absolute value** of the previous. This means you should probably be looking for points of intersection with the y-axis, but you might have just seen the equation and thought "Oh, this is a fourth degree equation, so the result will always be positive," but I can't really tell.

Other than that, if you just evaluated the integral at 4 and 2 and subtracted the two numbers, you should be golden :)